# table row :nth-child(odd) of [attribute=value]

Tags: css, sass

I want each odd `tr` that the `data-tt-parent-id` is 1 to be have a different background, is it possible to do in CSS? I found a code that can be done for the `li` but not working for `tr`

```css
.table tr [data-tt-parent-id="1"]:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color:blue;
}
li[data-tt-parent-id="1"]:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
    <tr data-tt-parent-id="1">
        <th>Table<th>
    </tr>
    <tr data-tt-parent-id="1">
        <td>Attribute 1<td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-tt-parent-id="1">
        <td>Attribute 1<td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-tt-parent-id="1">
        <td>Attribute 1<td>
    </tr>
</table>
<ol>
    <li data-tt-parent-id="1"></li>
    <li data-tt-parent-id="1"></li>
    <li data-tt-parent-id="1"></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Remove extra space just after `tr`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the spacing between your attribute selector

```
.table tr [data-tt-parent-id="1"]:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color:blue;
}
```

```css
.table tr[data-tt-parent-id="1"]:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color:blue;
}
li[data-tt-parent-id="1"]:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
    <tr data-tt-parent-id="1">
        <th>Table<th>
    </tr>
    <tr data-tt-parent-id="1">
        <td>Attribute 1<td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-tt-parent-id="1">
        <td>Attribute 1<td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-tt-parent-id="1">
        <td>Attribute 1<td>
    </tr>
</table>
<ol>
    <li data-tt-parent-id="1"></li>
    <li data-tt-parent-id="1"></li>
    <li data-tt-parent-id="1"></li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the space after tr and you're good to go:

```css
.table tr[data-tt-parent-id="1"]:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color:blue;
}
li[data-tt-parent-id="1"]:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
    <tr data-tt-parent-id="1">
        <th>Table<th>
    </tr>
    <tr data-tt-parent-id="1">
        <td>Attribute 1<td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-tt-parent-id="1">
        <td>Attribute 1<td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-tt-parent-id="1">
        <td>Attribute 1<td>
    </tr>
</table>
<ol>
    <li data-tt-parent-id="1"></li>
    <li data-tt-parent-id="1"></li>
    <li data-tt-parent-id="1"></li>
</ol>
```